# Create Program Ala IRC Client, FICS Client

Tags: winforms, web-services, telnet, irc

Forgive me if my question sounds silly.

I aspire my program to be database-driver independent. So I plan to make it ala IRC Client or FICS Client.

1. What kind of server are FICS(Free Internet Chess Server) and IRC Server?
2. Is it true for the server part, I have to configure a telnet server?
3. If it is true, is it the only choice?
4. If I choose telnet server, can I build a client using c# .net winform?
5. Is a ASP.Net Webservice is a much better solution?

For the client part, I will use c# .net winform.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some googling..

1. I suppose FICS is a telnet server, but clearly a client could connect to the server through telnet connection: http://blog.mekk.waw.pl/archives/7-How-to-write-a-FICS-bot-part-I.html
2. I've test KpyM server (a telnet server for Win: http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm), the server is sufficent to achieve what I plan to do.
3. I think ASP.Net Webservice is one of the other choices instead of telnet. If someone knows any other, please let me know.
4. There are many libraries for Telnet for .Net, I've test one of the libraries (http://www.dart.com/telnet-net-code-examples-samples.aspx), so the answer is YES.
5. I'll leave this one because I don't go in deep for both of the solutions (ASP.Net webservice and telnet)

I wonder why this particular area of IT knowledge doesn't get many responses. In my case is NONE.